# Для чего необходим второй метод в данном коде?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего необходим метод double distance(Point p) {
            return distance(p.x, p.y);  ?

Спасибо!!!

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    double distance(int х, int у) {
        int dx = this.x - х;
        int dy = this.y - у;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }


    double distance(Point p) {
        return distance(p.x, p.y);  // **ДЛЯ ЧЕГО необходим данный метод? При компиляции код все равно работает!!!**
    }
}



public class PointDist {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point p2 = new Point(30, 40);

        System.out.println("p1 = " + p1.x + ", " + p1.y);
        System.out.println("p2 = " + p2.x + ", " + p2.y);

        System.out.println("p1.distance(p2) = " + p1.distance(p2));
        System.out.println("p1.distance(60, 80) = " + p1.distance(60, 80));

    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
С:\> java PointDist

р1 = 0, 0

р2 = 30, 40

р1.distance(p2) = 50.0

p1.distance(60, 80) = 100.0
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ни понимаю, кому сие вздумалось минусовать? Очевидно что человек хочет разобраться. Хотя, конечно вопрос довольно простой.

Answer (score 1):

Этот метод видимо нужен для вычисления расстояния между точками.
Он просто берет из нее x и y  и передает в метод, который уже проводит вычисления.

Comment: То есть, по сути без него можно обойтись? Поскольку расстояние между точками вычисляет метод   double distance(int х, int у) {
        int dx = this.x - х;
        int dy = this.y - у;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

Comment: Можно только если вручную передавать координаты, то есть писать не p1.distance(p2), а p1.distance(p2.x,p2.y).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уберете этот участок кода, то без него не будет работать

```
System.out.println("p1.distance(p2) = " + p1.distance(p2));
```

И как следствие, программа выдаст ошибку компиляции. 
Потому что, этот метод на вход принимает *объект* типа точка (`Point`) у которого два поля.
Метод `double distance(int х, int у)`  принимает на вход два *примитива* типа `int`.

В вашей программе использован прием, который в литературе именуют *перегрузка методов* - т.е. два метода с одинаковым названием принимают на вход данные различных типов.

Компилятор получая команду `p1.distance(p2);`как бы спрашивает, а есть ли метод `distance`  который принимает на вход объект типа точка? 
Когда вы говорите компилятору `p1.distance(60, 80)` компилятор как бы задается вопросом, а есть ли метод `distance` который принимает на вход два примитива типа `int`?